# Nested insert in Linq to SQL?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

How do i put a nested insert into database using Linq to SQL

my Table is like this:

```
[Post]
--Post ID
--Post Title

[Attachment]
--Post ID (PFK)
--AttachmentID (PK)
--IMGID (FK)
--VIDID (FK)

[IMG]
--IMGID (PK)
```

it's a M:N table

basically when i submit a form , it go together with the attachments within the form. Im ok with insert Post, but strugling with the inserting attachments since i dont have any POST ID yet...

so what do you think is the best solution for this kind of problem?

Thank you

Comment: Did you find the solution for M:N relation ? If yes, please post the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a two-way [Association](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629295.aspx) between Post and Attachment, so you can do the following:

```
Post post = new Post { /* Set some fields perhaps */ };
Attachment attachment = new Attachment { /* Same here */ };
attachment.Post = post; // That is the association you need to create
dataContext.Posts.InsertOnSubmit(post);
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

LINQ-to-SQL will then handle the insertion of the Attachment(s) automatically.

I haven't used the DBML designer in a while, but I'm fairly sure you can say that a Post has Attachments and that an Attachment has a Post. And when you say `attachment.Post = post`, the setter for `Post` internally will do `_post.Attachments.Add(attachment)` where `_post` is a private member of the `Attachment` entity. Then, when you submit the Post, it will loop through the Attachments and insert them too.

Comment: i think this is M:1 how about M:N between post and IMG?